# Find filenames with certain characters

Tags: search, powershell-2.0

This is my first post :D ... I have never needed to post since all my answers have always been already answered.  I look but didn't find anything to answer this.

I have a directory ( call it temp ) in C:\ and I need to find all files in it (recursively) that contain ANY of these characters ~!@#$%^&*()+.,  OR a space.
I then need them listed with their location, I dont care about the date or permissions (infact I would prefer them removed)

I also need the option to filter *.htm

I tried playing with GCI and Select-String, but select-string kept reading the content of my files and I am not very good with regular expressions.

Thanks in advance for the help, I know the people on here know their stuff (4 years before I had to post a question :D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "c:\PST\"
$files = ($files | Where-Object {$_.BaseName.IndexOfAny("~!@#$%^&*()+., ".ToCharArray()) -ne -1})
$files
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, minor formatting changes to have it suit my needs fully.  I posted my end result below.

$files = Get-ChildItem -recurse "C:\Robo\SUDIT_PPKB\" -include "*.htm" $files = ($files | Where-Object {$_.BaseName.IndexOfAny("~!@#$%^&*()+., ".ToCharArray()) -ne -1}) Foreach ($file in $files) { $out = $file.DirectoryName+"\"+$file.Name Write-Host $out } Write-Host $files.length